# Which concept should I use for a list of names?

Tags: vectors, terminology

I have a $n$ sized vector. And I want to relate each element with a name.

Which mathematical concept should I use for the collection of string that can be indexed? For example the $i$th element of the vector correspond to the $i$th name of X?

Since it is a set of strings I can't say it is a vector... Can this be called ordered-set?

Comment: I would call it a *list*.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Mabye I was taking it to complicated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n$ is specified, it is called an [$n$-tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple). A [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family) is an $n$-tuple for an unspecified $n$, or an infinite sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification between n-tuple and list. $n$ will vary time to time for my case, so a list it is.